# Add an Image to a button in a user control from a local folder that can be changed later by the end user

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image, user-controls

I'm working on the learn by doing principle and am creating a standalone user control in wpf that can then be used in future projects.

I have several buttons in this control, each of which has an image property defined as a dependency property to allow the end user to use whichever image they prefer.

In xaml the button is defined like so:

```
<Button Background="#00000000" x:Name="First" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ToolTip="Go to First Record.">
            <StackPanel Margin="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageFirst, ElementName=DN}"
                   Width="{Binding ImageFirstWidth, ElementName=DN}"
                   Height="{Binding ImageFirstHeight, ElementName=DN}"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding TextFirst,ElementName=DN}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

and the corresponding image dependency property is defined thus:

```
Public Property ImageFirst() As ImageSource
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(ImageFirstProperty), ImageSource)
    End Get
    Set(value As ImageSource)
        SetValue(ImageFirstProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property


Public Shared ReadOnly ImageFirstProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageFirst", GetType(ImageSource), GetType(DataNavigator), New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing))
```

This functions exactly as intended, giving the end user the opportunity to select whatever image they choose for the button.

What I would like to do now is add a set of default images for the butoons.  I have created a folder in the project (Imaginatively called 'Images') to which I have added a set of images to be used as defaults.  Am I right in thinking that if I change the UIPropertyMetadata part of the dependency property declaration from nothing to a reference to one of these images that image will be used as the default but still allow the end user to select another if they so choose.

If that is the case how should I define the UIPropertMetadata part.  I tried UIPropertyMetadata("\Images\first16.png") but it didn't appear to work.

Many thanks for any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up default image is a little bit more complicated. You need to create an object of BitmapImage class with properly initialised Uri. That's how I have it in my code:

```
private static readonly ImageSource DefaultImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyAppNamespace;component/Images/default.png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

public static readonly DependencyProperty PictureSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PictureSource", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (RecordPicture), new PropertyMetadata(DefaultImage));

public ImageSource PictureSource
{
    get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(PictureSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PictureSourceProperty, value); }
}
```